# How to get the SessionID from soap:header?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I got a soap xml response and I need the SessionID. I tried to use SimpleXml_load_string but got a empty object back. Has anybody any idea how to get the SessionID?

This is the xml response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Header>
    <Header xmlns="http://www.twinfield.com/">
        <SessionID>ca363c52-c12f-4988-b06a-e0c41788e254</SessionID>
    </Header>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <LogonResponse xmlns="http://www.twinfield.com/">
        <LogonResult>Ok</LogonResult>
        <nextAction>None</nextAction>
        <cluster>https://c3.twinfield.com</cluster>
    </LogonResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [DOM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). This is one way:

```
$s = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Header>
    <Header xmlns="http://www.twinfield.com/">
        <SessionID>ca363c52-c12f-4988-b06a-e0c41788e254</SessionID>
    </Header>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <LogonResponse xmlns="http://www.twinfield.com/">
        <LogonResult>Ok</LogonResult>
        <nextAction>None</nextAction>
        <cluster>https://c3.twinfield.com</cluster>
    </LogonResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

$doc   = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML( $s );
echo $doc->getElementsByTagName('SessionID')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some thing useful here.Read this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/soap4r/-5IwhynDoEU:

and 
https://scn.sap.com/thread/3543465